# How to sort children by value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links with span values that I want to sort by.

http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/

In this example I want to sort by amount.

HTML:

```
<a id = "sortamount" class = "sort"><span>amount</span></a>

<div id='entrytable'> 
    <a class="entrylink" href="/link">

                <span class = "entry amount">10</span>

                <span class = "entry rating">11</span>

                <span class = "entry price">12</span>

            </a><br>
      <a class="entrylink" href="/link">

                <span class = "entry amount">15</span>

                <span class = "entry rating">16</span>

                <span class = "entry price">100</span>

            </a><br>
     <a class="entrylink" href="/link">

                <span class = "entry amount">13</span>

                <span class = "entry rating">12</span>

                <span class = "entry price">11</span>

            </a><br>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#sortamount').on('click', function() {
    var entries = document.getElementsByClassName('entrylink'); //nodelist
    var sorted = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) { 
        var value = entries[i].children('span.amount').val();
        sorted.push(value);
    }

    sorted.sort();
    $('#entrytable').html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) { 
        //find entrylink with sorted amount
        entries.filter(function(){return this.children('a span.amount').val() == sorted[i]});
        //append to entrytable
    }
});
```

Right now I'm getting an error at

```
var value = entries[i].children('span.amount').val();
```

saying

```
'[object HTMLCollection]' is not a function (evaluating 'entries[i].children('span.amount')')
```

What's wrong? Why can't I add the value of the amount to the sorted array?

Comment: what's the offers in your code?

Comment: oh my bad - i refactored the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to sort a list I think it can be much simpler if you use some of the jQuery power:

```
$('#sortamount').on('click', function () {
    $('.entrylink').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).find('.amount').text() - $(b).find('.amount').text();
    })
    .appendTo('#entrytable');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/2/

<sub>I made `a` block with CSS for convenience to get rid of `<br>` tags.</sub>

Comment: could you explain how `return $(a).find('.amount').text() - $(b).find('.amount').text();` works?

Comment: i posted this follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799424/how-does-this-jquery-sort-function-work

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
var value = $(entries[i]).children('span.amount').val();
```

Now you are wrapping the `entries[i]` to be used with jquery methods.

Comment: is that necessary? can I not use javascript.jquery()?

I mean entries[i].children() should also work, not?

Comment: I believe the same issue will occur inside the `.filter()` callback. Swap `this.children(...)` with `$(this).children(...)` -- that said, it appears OP is not using the returned (filtered) collection for anything? Or am I missing something.

Comment: Yes, wrapping is necessary to use jquery's methods

Comment: @C-link If he had used `var entries = $(".entrylink")` and then `entries.eq(i)` it would have been a jquery object already.

Comment: The more common way to do this is the use of jquery's `.each()`.