# How does this jQuery sort function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

This is a follow up question to
[How to sort children by value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757904/how-to-sort-children-by-value-in-jquery)

This is the code for sorting a bunch of links by the span with the amount value:

```
$('#sortamount').on('click', function () {
    $('.entrylink').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).find('.amount').text() - $(b).find('.amount').text();
    })
    .appendTo('#entrytable');
});
```

I don't completely understand this line:

```
return $(a).find('.amount').text() - $(b).find('.amount').text();
```

and how .appendTo clears the table before appending the newly sorted entry links to the table. How does the sorting happen? Does .appendTo automatically replace the entrytable's contents with the newly sorted contents?

Comment: `sort` isn't a jQuery function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - since `$('.entrylink')` is not an array, but is a jQuery object, then `$('.entrylink').sort()` is not the standard array sort.  It's a method on the jQuery object.  It may (and probably does) use the underlying array sort, but it is a different method.

Comment: @jfriend00: apparently it is the internal array sort (try doing `$(document).sort`) -- I'll see where's the original code.

Comment: @jfriend00: take a look at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L120

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Great idea to point at master. That file does not contain the word “sort” any more.

Comment: @RobertSiemer the sarcasm was surely appreciated. I'm not sure why I linked it to master on that old comment, but the link at the time would have been to https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/4dec426aa2a6cbabb1b064319ba7c272d594a688/src/core.js#L120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an arithmetic operations the values of both the LHS and RHS are converted to a Number before the `-` operation is done.

Here we are actually sorting the DOM elements, so after sorting you have the DOM elements in a new order. when you use append on a set of DOM elements which are already present in the DOM it will be removed from the old location and will be placed on the new location.

Comment: so when the difference is positive, a is placed after b and vice versa? what is the process of iterating over all the elements? does it go in sequence? say you have 1, 3, 4, and 2 - does it just cycle through over and over again until it's completely sorted? like 1, 3, 4, 2 -> 1, 3, 2, 4 -> 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: @mango - read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.  The jQuery method is actually a different `.sort()` method attached to the jQuery object, but is uses this array sort method described in that MDN article to do its job.