# Sort inside children, by label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Object with 3 main arrays (key:1, key:2, key:3) and inside each of them I have children.

I need to sort this children for each main array by label, so that at the end I keep the same structure, however with a sorted list.

I also understand that sorting with numbers is not the same as sorting with strings.

Thank you for any help. The solutions can be either in JS or jQuery.

```js
var agents_B = [ 
        {key:1, label:"Main", open: true, children: [
            {key:111, label:"Ricardo Contente", 'tel':'0799434787','profile_picture':'profile_1.png', 'checkinout':'true', 'skill':'PW'},
            {key:112, label:"Antonio Peleaz", 'profile_picture':'profile_2.png', 'checkinout':'false','skill':'PW'},
            {key:113, label:"Vahxid Musa", 'profile_picture':'profile_3.png','checkinout':'true','skill':'SA'},
            {key:114, label:"Mari Jovic", 'profile_picture':'profile_4.png','checkinout':'false','skill':'HL'},
            {key:115, label:"Dieter Streuli", 'profile_picture':'profile_2.png','checkinout':'true','skill':'HL', 'changed':'true'},
            {key:121, label:"Marcos Alonso", 'profile_picture':'profile_1.png','skill':'HL'},
            {key:122, label:"Rui Morais", 'profile_picture':'profile_4.png','skill':'HL'},
            {key:123, label:"Carlos Marcos", 'profile_picture':'profile_3.png','skill':'PW', 'changed':'true'},
            {key:124, label:"Ramon  Dikstaal"},
            {key:131, label:"Matthias Bürgi"},
            {key:132, label:"Thomas Bosshard", 'profile_picture':'profile_1.png'},
            {key:141, label:"Jana", 'profile_picture':'profile_2.png'},
            {key:142, label:"Michel"},
        ]},
        {key:2, label:"B/A", open:false, children: [
            {key:21, label:"Jana Mueller"},
            {key:22, label:"Michel Bürgi"},
        ]},
        {key:3, label:"Not assigned", open:true, children: [
            {key:'not_assigned', label:'', tel:'', skill:'', profile_picture:''}
        ]}
    ];
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle like this poster did? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757904/how-to-sort-children-by-value-in-jquery  http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, all you have to do is to loop through `agents_B` and *for each* item you have to *sort* `item.children` by *label*, in alphabetical order

Comment: @secan thats it

Comment: @KontYentE, prefect; have you tried to "translate" that sentence in code, then? What did you obtain?

Comment: var i;
    for (i = 0; i < agents_B.length; i++) {
        console.log(agents_B[i].children.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.label) - parseFloat(b.label)));
    }

Comment: `label` is a string (e.g. `"Ricardo Contente"`); why are you trying to parse it into a floating point number? `parseFloat(a.label)` will always result in `NaN`

Comment: @secan you are right. my mistake. What should I use instead?

Comment: @KontYentE you sort string alphabetically by comparing them and returning `1` if `stringA > stringB`, `-1` if `stringA < stringB` or `0`. If you want a reverse alphabetic order, you swap the `-1` and `1` return values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```js
var agents_B = [ 
    {key:1, label:"Main", open: true, children: [
        {key:111, label:"Ricardo Contente", 'tel':'0799434787','profile_picture':'profile_1.png', 'checkinout':'true', 'skill':'PW'},
        {key:112, label:"Antonio Peleaz", 'profile_picture':'profile_2.png', 'checkinout':'false','skill':'PW'},
        {key:113, label:"Vahxid Musa", 'profile_picture':'profile_3.png','checkinout':'true','skill':'SA'},
        {key:114, label:"Mari Jovic", 'profile_picture':'profile_4.png','checkinout':'false','skill':'HL'},
        {key:115, label:"Dieter Streuli", 'profile_picture':'profile_2.png','checkinout':'true','skill':'HL', 'changed':'true'},
        {key:121, label:"Marcos Alonso", 'profile_picture':'profile_1.png','skill':'HL'},
        {key:122, label:"Rui Morais", 'profile_picture':'profile_4.png','skill':'HL'},
        {key:123, label:"Carlos Marcos", 'profile_picture':'profile_3.png','skill':'PW', 'changed':'true'},
        {key:124, label:"Ramon  Dikstaal"},
        {key:131, label:"Matthias Bürgi"},
        {key:132, label:"Thomas Bosshard", 'profile_picture':'profile_1.png'},
        {key:141, label:"Jana", 'profile_picture':'profile_2.png'},
        {key:142, label:"Michel"},
    ]},
    {key:2, label:"B/A", open:false, children: [
        {key:21, label:"Jana Mueller"},
        {key:22, label:"Michel Bürgi"},
    ]},
    {key:3, label:"Not assigned", open:true, children: [
        {key:'not_assigned', label:'', tel:'', skill:'', profile_picture:''}
    ]}
];

const sortByLabel = (arr) => {
  arr.sort((a, b) => {
if(a.label > b.label) return 1;
else if(a.label < b.label) return -1;
else return 0;
  });
  return arr;
}

agents_B.forEach((item, index) => {
  agents_B[index] = {...item, children: sortByLabel(item.children)};
})
console.log(agents_B);
```

Answer (score 1):

JS only

```
agents_B.forEach((agent) => (agent.children.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.label.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.label.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
})) );
```

Comment: Is there any diff between lowercase and uppercase?